# How do I loop round a switch statement in C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Studentname;
        string retry = "No";

        Console.WriteLine("What is the Student's name? ");

        while (retry != "No")
             Console.WriteLine("What is the Student's name? ");

        Studentname = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (Studentname) {
            case "George":
                Console.WriteLine("Yes in the list");
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;

            case "Goblin":
                Console.WriteLine("Yes in the list");
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;

            case "Peter":
                Console.WriteLine("Yes in the list");
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;

            case "TJ":
                Console.WriteLine("Yes in the list");
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Not in the list");
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to retry?");
                retry = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to loop around the case statement if the answer is incorrect, however the statement always breaks and I am unable to loop. How would I solve this issue?

Comment: In your case, `do..while()` loop is better.

Comment: "Unlike the while statement, a do-while loop is executed one time before the conditional expression is evaluated." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx

Comment: Would you consider using if statements here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword "break" only breaks out of the first code block (space in-between the {...}) it is in. The break in your switches shouldn't interfere with your while loop at all.

The issue is that you have no brackets after your while loop so it only acts on the line directly after.

Below is probably what you were looking for.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Studentname;
        string retry = "No";

        Console.WriteLine("What is the Student's name? ");
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the Student's name? ");
            Studentname = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (Studentname)
            {
                case "George":
                    Console.WriteLine("Yes in the list");
                    //Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                case "Goblin":
                    Console.WriteLine("Yes in the list");
                    //Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                case "Peter":
                    Console.WriteLine("Yes in the list");
                    //Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                case "TJ":
                    Console.WriteLine("Yes in the list");
                    //Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Not in the list");
                    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to retry?");
                    retry = Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
            }
        } while (retry != "No");
    }
}
```

EDIT: Your while loop also was never entered. You set "retry" to "No" then check if it is not "No". To solve this you can either use a "do ... while()" loop which always loops at least one time or you can change the first assignment of "retry" to anything but "No".

EDIT 2: @Kason is correct. I didn't realize your actual goal was to exit if the name was found. If that is the case then a "do ... while()" is your best option.

Comment: If the retry initial value is No, it stil cannot run the code inside the loop.

Comment: Good points, I didn't actually look at the logic, just saw that the brackets where missing from the while loop. It should be good now.

Comment: I think you should also remove the Console.Readline() from within the switch statement. I don't think they serve any purpose - except for the one in the default branch.

Comment: Um... Your code now is different, if user input the name is in the list, it stil loop the question and ask again. For the original, it should be stop the loop.

Comment: @failedprogramming I don't quite know what the original questioners goal was. I don't know why you would want to read again but it's unclear if they are intended or not. I guess I will comment them out?

Comment: @failedprogramming For some developers, they would leave a Console.ReadLine() in the last of the program to stop exit for debug purpose.

Comment: @Kason Yeah I guess that would make sense if the program was supposed to stop looping after receiving a correct answer. I thought the poster wanted to keep looping until the user types "No". But i guess the question isn't very clear on that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could use this simple LINQ method:

```
string Studentnames[] = new string[]
{
    "George",
    "Goblin",
    "Peter",
    "TJ"
}

while (retry != "No")
{
    if (Studentnames.Contains(Studentname)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Yes in the list");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not in the list");
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to retry?");
        retry = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

But it is not working because you have forgotton to put the `{}` for the while statement.

Comment: The approach is good, the reason of someone giving down vote maybe is that you have not explan why the code not work in the question

Answer (score 0):

Add a left curly brace after the while statement, and a matching right curly brace at the bottom of your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are no curly brackets following the beginning of the `while` loop. That means that the `while` statement only applies to the immediately following line.

```
while (retry != "No")
    Console.WriteLine("What is the Student's name? ");
```

As was mentioned, `retry` starts off as "No". So when the `while` condition is evaluated it is false. The following line never executes because it's only supposed to execute if `retry != "No"`.

When you want `while` to apply to a block of statements, put them in curly braces.

```
while (retry != "No")
{
    //Everything inside these braces will execute if retry != "No".
    //If it gets to the end and retry still != "No" then it will repeat.
    //You'd most likely want to do something inside this loop sooner or
    //later that changes retry to something else so that the loop can
    //end. Or you can use "break" to exit the loop.
}
```